# Where to position include/require statements?

Tags: php

Do you position all of your `include_once` and `require_once` at the start of the file, so it's clear what it's dependencies are, or do you put them at the most local scope where they are used, for efficiency?

Let's say I have an error handling file which has a function to display an error message - would you ...

```
require_once('error_handling.php');
... lots of code ...
if ($should_be_true === False)
{
  ReportErrror();  // declared in error_handling.php
}
```

or do you

```
... lots of code ...
if ($should_be_true === False)
{
  require_once('error_handling.php');
  ReportErrror();  // declared in error_handling.php
}
```

hmm, looks like they deleted the `best-practise` tag, along with `subjective` in the great tag purge of '10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a matter of taste for the most part.

In C/C++ style, I always put them on top, so - as you mentioned - the dependencies are immediately clear. Also, it gives you the option to rearrange the order of inclusion (which should normally never matter).

Now, since this is a runtime affair (unlike C/C++), it would make sense to postpone including huge files that are rarely ever needed.

It's a matter of balance - cleaner code (IMHO) vs performance. I would tend towards cleaner code, unless you have a PHP file that is a) called a lot, b) uses a huge PHP file that is c) almost never needed.

Comment: I think that I lean towards you way of thinking.

Answer (score 2):

I'd most definitely go with the second example, because to load in stuff that potentially wouldn't be used is just evil.

Comment: Placing the require like the second example also makes it clearer to the reader when the require is needed. Sometimes requires are left in code when they are no longer needed. I would only put it at the top if it contains something that will be used in many different places in the associated code.

Answer (score 1):

Meh. Totally dependent on the situation.

If it's a small include and you're going to use it in 95% of situations, top is fine. Top really is fine for almost all cases.

But if it's an absolutely huge library to, say, parse something that will only come up in 5% of requests, require when needed. It might be worth making a comment at the top to make the dependency known, however—happy medium?

Anyway. It's a judgment call every time. Best not worry too much about the performance issue for the uncertain cases until milliseconds of performance actually become an issue for you. (And wouldn't that sort of popularity be an excellent issue to have?)

Comment: +1 for you (and all who replied), but if it's a large library then I would probably split it into multiple smaller files ... and then (re)curse ;-)

Comment: @LeonixSolutions: in that instance I generally mean third-party libraries, which sometimes come in large, inseparable portions :/